# Is there a way to get records into a form from another table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I don't know much about programming so i created this database using Access. 
This one is kinda tough for me to do. 
There are  few tables in the database. Employee ID and training they got and minutes. 
What I want to know is a possible way to get training information relating to employee's past 3 years and input them into a single text-box named as previous visits where i can create the minute.
All these tables are linked by the Employee ID.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could have some vba code to store the employee id
and then loop their training in the training table.  The insert the 
values into a tblEmployeeTrainingRecords table.